# The chain's spread_inside not work in constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

> I have a image view which I want to set it to the horizontal right
> side in constraint layout, but the layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf
> constraint seems not work in imageView.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintainer_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@{maintainer.name}"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="maintainer_name" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/maintainer_right_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/maintainer_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_right_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The screen which I want to get.
[image]

The screen actually I get.
[image]

**SOLUTION**

check another post [match parent width property not work in recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63934076/9768260)

Answer (score 1):

> Set first textview width as 0dp

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintainer_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@{maintainer.name}"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="maintainer_name" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="maintainer_right_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/maintainer_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_continue_as_guest" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: the textView can not reach the end of ConstraintLayout horizontal line, like the actually screen I show above.

Comment: If I set textView width to 0dp, I can not see it anymore.

Comment: Did you tried with code which I shared? I didn't understood your point

Comment: I find the issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63934076/9768260.