# match parent width property not work in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried to set the match_parent width property to the textView of viewHolder, but it works the same as the wrap_context.

```
// recyclerview
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/maintainer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:listMaintainer="@{viewModel.maintainers}"/>

// viewHolder item
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintainer_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="maintainer_name" />
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Mike M. because I use data binding in viewHolder and not correctly add it to adapter within `onCreateViewHolder` method, so it cause this issue.

Comment: Set start and end constrains for text View and set width to `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: If set width to 0dp, I will not see the textView again.

Comment: Are you sure you're inflating the layout correctly in your `Adapter`? You need to pass the `ViewGroup` parameter in `onCreateViewHolder()` as the parent in the `inflate()` call. If you pass `null` for it, you will get the behavior you're observing.

Answer (score 1):

Constraint layouts should not use `match_parent`. If I'm not mistaken you should get a warning in the IDE.

The way to do this is using `0dp` and constraint the end/start or top/bottom to the corresponding parent's sides.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />
```

*I've highlighted only the necessary changes and additions*

Answer (score 1):

When you make a child of a ConstraintLayout have a width of **match_parent**, there's no need to set an horizontal constraint (start and end). If you remove the line `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` from your TextView, it would render the exact way you want it to.

To recap, there are two ways you can do what you want to do. I illustrated the two approaches below:

1. Set the width of the TextView to `match_parent` and exclude any horizontal constraints:

   ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/maintainer_name"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:background="@color/color_black"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:text="maintainer_name" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

2. Set the width of the TextView to `0dp` and include horizontal constraints:

   ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/maintainer_name"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:background="@color/color_black"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:text="maintainer_name" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```